# Is $X_t = e^{\int_0^t B_sdB_s - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t B_s^2 dB_s}$ a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

> **Question**: Is $X_t = e^{\int_0^t B_sdB_s - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t B_s^2 dB_s}$ a martingale with respect to the filtration generated by $B_t$?

In order to determine whether the above expression is a martingale, I thought that it'd be a good first step to calculate each of the integrals in the exponent.

Thus, I first found that $\displaystyle \int_0^tB_sdB_s=\frac{B_t^2}{2}-\frac{t}{2}$ by using Ito's lemma on $B_s^2$ and manipulating the resulting equation.

However, I am not sure how to solve for the second integral, $
\displaystyle \int_0^tB_s^2dB_s$. I can't think of an expression on which to utilize Ito's lemma to be able to isolate for the given integral.

Am I even going about this question the right way? Do I need to solve for the integrals? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Computing the integrals in the exponent may not be necessary, at least not right away.  Let $X_t = \int_0^t (B_s - \frac{1}{2} B_s^2)\,dB_s$ be the process in the exponent, and use Ito's lemma to express $f(X_t)$ where $f(x) = e^x$.  If you see a bounded variation term, you definitely don't have a martingale.  Otherwise, you have a local martingale and can start investigating whether it is a martingale.